# Is there any way to include classes that are not used in controller with Swagger in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, yaml, swagger, swagger-maven-plugin

I'm using swagger-maven-plugin(kongchen) to generate static document and
I would like to generate yaml like this:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "Swagger example"
paths:
  /api/students:
    post:
      operationId: "addStudent"
      parameters:
      - in: "body"
        name: "body"
        required: false
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Student"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "successful operation"
          schema:
            type: "boolean"
definitions:
  Student:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      id:
        type: "integer"
        format: "int32"
        minimum: 1
        maximum: 20
      name:
        type: "string"
      surname:
        type: "string"
```

But i would also want plugin to include classes that are not defined in my controller.

my plugin setup:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <apiSources>
                        <apiSource>
                            <springmvc>true</springmvc>
                            <locations>
                                <location>
                                    mypackage
                                </location>
                            </locations>
                            <info>
                                <title>
                                    Swagger example
                                </title>
                                <version>
                                    1.0.0
                                </version>
                            </info>
                            <outputFormats>json,yaml</outputFormats>
                            <swaggerDirectory>generated</swaggerDirectory>
                            <swaggerApiReader>com.github.kongchen.swagger.docgen.reader.SpringMvcApiReader</swaggerApiReader>
                        </apiSource>
                    </apiSources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Adding dependency to swagger-hibernate-validations to enable the BeanValidator as a custom
                         model converter -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger-hibernate-validations</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Is there any way to achieve this goal using Swagger?
The main goal of it is to have yaml that i can import to Apicurio and use in my applications.

Or maybe is there any way to generate yaml that includes all classes like this without using it in any controller?

```
 @ApiModel
    public class Student {
        @Min(1)
        @Max(20)
        @ApiModelProperty
        private int id;
        @ApiModelProperty
        private String name;}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *classes that are not defined in my controller*?

Comment: For example i have Teacher class but its not used in my controller, and i would like to include them in yaml file.

Comment: But what is then the use of documenting something that the normal user can't interact with?

Comment: So i would like to have like a few shared classes that i could use in all of my front-end and back-end applications. I was using apicurio but i would like to validate Requests By adding Annotations on my Entities.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to include the models, request / response stubs?
If so you can use Swagger annotations

Method Level:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get Details", response = ResponseClassStub, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I would like to generate schema for classes, but without need to declare them in controller. Like in Apicurio You can create Data Types that are not used in any endpoint

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with micronaut.openapi to include yml files. For example, if you have an openapi schema in `openapi/mySchema.yml`, you can import it to your schema by putting the following line in `openapi.properties`:

```
micronaut.openapi.additional.files=openapi
```

Unfortunately this approach doesn't work if you need to use the class. You can have a class defined separately but you need to keep it in sync with mySchema.yml manually.